# Affinity Photo/ Gimp - Photoshop Liquify filter alternative

Tags: gimp, photoshop-effects, filter, affinity-designer

What's the alternative for Photoshop "Liquify" (Shift+Ctrl+X) filter in Affinity Photo, or Gimp?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question about graphic design, but about graphic design _tools_. The answer to this question is easily found online.

Comment: "The answer to this question is easily found online" It isn't. If you think that it is easy to found online, just rewrite it here, you can get points easily. "[..] is not a question about graphic design, but about graphic design tools." Graphics design tools are one of the topics of graphics design.

Comment: just check this meta discussion https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2463/should-extremely-basic-how-to-do-this-in-software-x-questions-be-off-topic

Comment: Maciej B - what is under discussion here is that here at GDSE, we prefer to have questions which will help a wider community, and which help elevate the general expertise of our community. We clearly state in our Tour page that "Graphic Design Stack Exchange is a question-and-answer site for graphic-design professionals, students, and enthusiasts...", so we welcome newer users and non-experts, but we ask a modicum of effort be shown in questions (e.g. show us what you've tried so far when failing to accomplish the required task) most "Where is button X?" questions don't fit - I felt yours did.

Comment: @PieBie: *because this is not a question about graphic design, but about graphic design* tools. – The vast majority of our questions is about graphic-design tools. — *The answer to this question is easily found online.* – That’s not a valid close reason. We want to be what is found online.

Comment: I don't mind basic how-to questions, but this is just borderline tech support. [This](https://i.imgur.com/cgEPRzd.png) is the result of a Google search. It's also easily found in the [GIMP documentation](https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-tool-warp.html).

 @Wrzlprmft: "We want to be what is found online." But we _do not_ want to replace every other online source. We want to be found for things that cannot be found yet, we do not want to be a mirror site for every manual out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Affinity Photo has an entire Liquify Persona... pretty effective.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]